# display only object name in input | FormControlName - Angular

Tags: angular

My input gets an object, I would like to see only the property "name" using formControlName.

Input only displays [object object]

Here's an example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbmqfe

Comment: Your stackblitz apprears to be working correctly, what is the issue here

Comment: Sorry man, I have solved this yesterday. For that reason it is working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that you have two formGroup.

```
  {{ formGroup.get('test').get('name').value | json }}
```